# Text Similarity - Cosine - Control

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, linguistics, quanteda, text2vec

I would like to ask you, if anybody could check my code, because it was behaving weird - not working, giving me errors to suddenly working without changing anything - the code will be at the bottom.

**Background**: So my goal is to calculate text similarity [cosine, for now] between **annual** statements given by several countries at the UN General Assembly. More specifically find similarity between statement x and statement y in given year and do it for all 45 years. So I can make a graph for its evolution.

**How I went about it:** So [im novice] I decided to do the work in several steps - finding the similarity of statements of country A to country B first, and then re-doing the work for other countries (country A stays, everything is to country A).

So I filtered statements for Country A, arranged by year. Did text-preprocessing (tokenization, to lower, stopwords, lemenization, bag-of-words). And then I made a TF-IDF matrix from it - named: **text.tokens.tfidf**

I did the same process for Country B, and got **text.tokensChina.tfidf** - just replacing all text.tokens to text.tokensChina on new paper. So each matrix contains tf-idf of annual statements from 1971 - 2005, where Rows = documents (years) and columns = terms.

**Calculating cosine similarity:** So I decided to use Text2Vec as is described [here](http://text2vec.org/similarity.html#cosine_similarity) - **however, I did not define common space and project documents to it** - dunno if it's crucial. And then decided to text two functions**sim2 and psim2** since I did not know the difference in parallel.

**What was wrong at the start:** When first running the functions, I was getting an error, probably telling me, that my lengths of columns in the two TF-IDF matrixes are not matched:

> ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE

However, re-running the code for all my steps and then trying again, it worked, but I did not change anything ...

**Results:** Result for the function sim2 is weird table [1:45, 1:45]. Clearly not what I wanted - one column with the similarity between the speech of Country A and country B in given year.

Result for the function psim2 is better - one column with the results [not sure, how right they are though].

**Technical questions:** Using Psim2 is what I wanna - Not I see that sim2 created something like correlation heat map, my bad. But why is the Psim2 function working, even when the length of columns is different (picture)? Also, did I not do anything wrong, especially when I did not create a common space?

**Code, picture:**

```
    # *** Text Pre-Processing with Quanteda *** 
      # 1. Tokenization
      text.tokens <- tokens(docs$text, what = 'word',
                          remove_numbers = TRUE,
                          remove_punct = TRUE,
                          remove_symbols = TRUE,
                          remove_hyphens = TRUE)

      # 2. Transform words to lower case
      text.tokens <- tokens_tolower(text.tokens)

      # 3. Removing stop-words (Using quanteda's built-in stopwords list)
      text.tokens <- tokens_select(text.tokens, stopwords(),
                                   selection = 'remove')
      # 4. Perform stemming on the tokens.
      text.tokens <- tokens_wordstem(text.tokens, language = 'english')

      # 5. Create bag-of-words model / document feature(frequance)
      text.tokens.dfm <- dfm(text.tokens, tolower = FALSE)

      # 6. Transform to a matrix to work with and inspect
      text.tokens.matrix <- as.matrix(text.tokens.dfm)
      dim(text.tokens.matrix)

    # *** Doing TF-IDF *** 
      # Defining Function for calculating relative term frequency (TF)
      term.frequency <- function(row) {
        row / sum(row)
      }
      # Defining Function for calculating inverse document frequency (IDF)
      inverse.doc.freq <- function(col) {
        corpus.size <- length(col)
        doc.count <- length(which(col > 0))

        log10(corpus.size / doc.count)
      }
      # Defining function for calculating TD-IDF
      tf.idf <- function(tf, idf) {
        tf * idf
      }

      # 1. First step, normalize all documents via TF.
      text.tokens.df <- apply(text.tokens.matrix, 1, term.frequency)
      dim(text.tokens.df)

      # 2. Second step, calculate the IDF vector 
      text.tokens.idf <- apply(text.tokens.matrix, 2, inverse.doc.freq)
      str(text.tokens.idf)

      # 3. Lastly, calculate TF-IDF for our corpus
        # Apply function on columns, because matrix is transposed from TF function  
        text.tokens.tfidf <- apply(text.tokens.df, 2, tf.idf, idf = text.tokens.idf)
        dim(text.tokens.tfidf)

      # Now, transpose the matrix back
        text.tokens.tfidf <- t(text.tokens.tfidf)
        dim(text.tokens.tfidf)

     # Cosine similarity using Text2Vec 
  similarity.sim2 <- sim2(text.tokensChina.tfidf, text.tokensChina.tfidf, method = "cosine", norm = "none")

  similarity.psim2 <- psim2(text.tokensChina.tfidf, text.tokensChina.tfidf, method = "cosine", norm = "none")
  similarity.psim2 <- as.data.frame(similarity.psim2)
```

**Global Enviroment picture:**
[Picture of my screen with Global Environment + Psim2 Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzZqU.png)

Comment: This is not really the kind of question for Stack Overflow.  You might do better to post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh thank you, was not aware of the code review :/

Comment: See `quanteda::dfm_tfidf()`.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can skin most of the preprocessing code, I just wanted to have it step by them cuz I am new to it so I remember it. Afterward will be using that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the outcome is, the whole thing is complete BS. Did not compare things in one vector space. Not to mention, the best method is to use doc2vec but I tried to figure it out for several days and got nowhere, unfortunately.